# Do I have malware? Mysterious connection made by app

Tags: security, malware

I have Little Snitch installed. I use an app [that shall remain nameless in case this is a false alarm]. I was recently reviewing connection attempts in Little Snitch, and it claims that [this app] accessed "[anonops.com](http://anonops.com)" I checked this website and it seems to be an IRC server run for/by Anonymous (?) but I don't really know.

Can anyone shed any light as to why [this app] was trying to access this domain? It's not for software updates, because that it requests updates from [this app's official domain]. I don't want to accuse anyone of making malware, but obviously if the developer was responsible I can't just ask them and assume I'd be given an honest answer.

I'm running Mountain Lion and follow security best practices (no pirated software, don't open/install packages unless I know where they come from, browse the web with Java disabled, use Click2Flash and AdBlock, have "open safe files" disabled, etc.) so I wouldn't have thought I'd have been infected with anything.

I just want to emphasise I'm not accusing the developer of anything. Maybe it's another app just piggybacking off [this app], or maybe there's a completely legitimate reason for this that I don't know about. I just want to understand if there's something I need to be concerned about or not.

Comment: Probably a case of a different domain hosted on the developer's server. I think your best bet would be to contact the developer and ask him directly.

Comment: This could be it. Little Snitch does a reverse DNS lookup, and I think [this app's] website uses CloudFlare for content delivery. I have asked the developer for comment, but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with naming the app - it would probably help other people in reproducing your issue.

Comment: Without knowing what the App is, I can't help shed any light on this matter, and I'm not sure anyone else can either. If Little Snitch reports that the App is attempting to connect to that domain, it is. There is no "false positive" about it. The only question left to ask is WHY is the App connecting to their domain, and on what port.

Comment: It would really help to name the app. For example many Twitter Clients will request website URLs to see if they need to unwrap shortened-URLs like t.co or bit.ly so they can display the full domain to the user. This will, of course, show a request to said domain in LittleSnitch. Also, you don't give any details on which port/protocol was accessed. (Seems you tried 80/tcp aka http already.)